# How to add optional filters/query parameters in Django extra actions

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have a ViewSet with extra action shown below

```
class Parent(
  mixin.CreateModelMixin, 
  mixin.ListModelMixin, 
  mixin.RetrieveModelMixin, 
  viewset.GenericViewSet
):
  queryset = Model.objects.all()
  serializer_class = ParentSerializer
  ...
  ...
  @action(detail=True, methods=["get", "post"], serializer_class=SomeSerializerclass)
  def extra(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == "GET":
      .... do something
    else:  # request.method is POST
      .... do something
    ...
```

I want to add few optional query parameters to this extra action endpoint like:
`parent/1/extra/?name=somename` and this will filter the data for this name if request.method is `GET`. Also, this query param can be multiple like: `parent/1/extra/?name=somename&surname=foo`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Typically, you use a `FilterSet` for that to do the advanced filtering.

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem How can I add FilterSet to this extra action? Can we add `filterset_fields` or `filterset_class`?

Comment: Well exactly how does `extra` look like? Looks more like a `ListAPIView`?

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem I have updated my question. when `extra`  is called with these query params it should display filtered data, basically a json or list.

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem Yes, kind of, with also having `post` method.